# Error in fetching records in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-service

I am Trying to make code for fetch records in angularjs but didn't get any solution please help me

```
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="customersController"> 

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names">
    {{ x.Status }}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>
<script src= "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
function customersController($scope,$http) { 

    $http.get('http://192.168.0.62:8081/DataAccess/rest/userservice/quicksignup/email/123@gmail.com')
    .success(function(response) {$scope.names = response;});
}
</script>
```

O/p of `json[{"Status":"Unverified","EmailForVerification":"Sent","User_role":"User","signup":"true"}]`

Comment: Your code is fine, `console.log` the `response` to see if you are getting the right format

Comment: then it's most likely problem with your service, it might be the cross domain issue in which case you will have to add CORS to your service http://enable-cors.org/server.html
Different port = different domain (for some browsers ;) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks fine. Please check if IP address and port you are running the angular application is same where your webservice is deployed i.e 192.168.0.62:8081

If they are different, please click F12 on browser (Chrome) and click Console Tab to see the output. If you are getting CORS error something like below -

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Try adding below line in webservice implementation. "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" For more info see - http://enable-cors.org/index.html